# Ruby - working with `require` command

Tags: ruby, require

I am editing a gem in which there are the usual `require` commands, pointing at the loaded gem (the gem I'm talking about is called `nirvana`, and the files in it contain `require 'nirvana'`, `require 'nirvana/shell'` and so on).

When I use the bin-file of the application (`/mypath/nirvana/bin/nirvana`), I want the `require 'nirvana'` command written inside it to point to the files in the local fork of that gem (the ones I am editing), and I want not to load the original nirvana gem, that is installed with the classic `gem install`.

I don't want to substitute all the `require 'nirvana'` commands with

```
require File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__)) + '/../lib/nirvana.rb'
```

... this would resolve my problem, but it's ugly! Is there a way to do not load nirvana gem, and to make `require 'nirvana'` load my libraries (maybe adding them in the $LOAD_PATH...) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only be 'requiring' `nirvana.rb` once, if you're doing so from your gems binary executable. So this line only needs to appear once. It's quite common to see it appear in these files.

Do note your example can be better written as

```
require File.expand_path('../lib/nirvana.rb', __FILE__)
```

As [File::expand_path](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/File.expand_path) takes an optional second argument (a directory String).

A lot of authors will also shift the `lib` directory into the $LOAD_PATH before executing the binary so the local files are loaded before attempting to load any installed gems.

Comment: File.expand_path with two arguments is a great suggestion. In addition, I did not know that it is possible to overwrite loadings using $LOAD_PATH.

Comment: Yup, if you shift the 'lib' directory into the $LOAD_PATH (make sure it's shift, so it comes BEFORE any rubygem load paths), and then you can use require 'nirvana/something' within your nirvana.rb file

Answer (score 3):

You might be running into the `require` vs. `require_relative` conundrum in 1.9+.

`require` is good for loading a gem that is loaded via the normal gems paths, i.e., installed into Ruby's space.

`require_relative` is good for loading relative to a particular file, for instance, if you're loading a module you wrote and its in the same or a sub-directory or relative directory of yours.

```
`require_relative 'some/sub/dir/to/file'`
```

Comment: `require_relative` is an appreciated discovery, it is very useful if you don't mind the compatibility with 1.8. (And also in that case, You can implement the method according on `RUBY_VERSION`). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/), have a look at [gemsets](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/gemsets/).  You can create a gemset that doesn't have the `nirvana` gem installed, then when you `require 'nirvana'` you'll only get your local libraries required, as there isn't a nirvana gem to include.

(I'm assuming you're using ruby 1.9, as if you're using 1.8 you could just omit `require 'rubygems'`.)

Comment: This is a good answer too, but I don't want to need Rvm to resolve this problem... thank you, though!